# Retreive the Quantity used to define a Unit in Java Unit of Measurement API (JSR 385)

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jsr

I'm using JSR-385 with the RI (Indriya). I have a `Quantity` `q1` and defined as such:

```java
QuantityFormat qf = ServiceProvider.current().getFormatService().getQuantityFormat();
Quantity q1 = qf.parse("10 J"); // Here strings are constants but they are coming from user input
                                  // The Unit of Measure can/will vary.
```

**Now I want to understand what `Quantity` (i.e. what interface in `javax.measure.quantity`) `q1` is measuring, if any.**

I can retrieve `Dimension` but that is not the same thing:

```java
Quantity q2. qf.parse("10 N*m");
System.stdout.println(q1.compareTo(q2)); // prints "0", but torque and energy are not the same thing
```

As additional "free rant", the API of `Dimension.getBaseDimensions()` are so inconsistent Instead of returning always a `Map<Dimension, Integer>` they just do so when the Dimension is not related to a base dimension, in which case it returns `null` (it could have more consistently still return the Map containing a single `Map.Entry`), except in the case of `UnitDimension.NONE` when it follows again the expected behavior and returns an empty `Map`.